# JSON.NET Serializer for WCF service hosted in Windows Service or command line executable

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

There is a WCF REST service hosted in Windows Service or in command line executable. I would like to replace the default DataContractJsonSerializer with [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) serializer.

There is a similar question with a minor difference, that it uses IIS: [How to set Json.Net as the default serializer for WCF REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118504/how-to-set-json-net-as-the-default-serializer-for-wcf-rest-service).

Code proposed there does not work when hosted outside the IIS. 
It throws the following exception:
 *'ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailable' cannot be invoked within the current hosting environment. This API requires that the calling application be hosted in IIS or WAS.*

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code should work; just remove the `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements]` attribute from the service, since it doesn't really apply for self-hosted services. You can also use a custom message formatter to replace the serializer, as described at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I gave it up for the moment and will go with the DataContractJsonSerializer for a while. I'll accept your answer as it sounds logical and I'll check it later on maybe.