# Do not serialize fields under external conditions C#

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, request, response

I need to get subset in the REST response. How I can reach that?
For example, we have class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Response
{
    [DataMember]        
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string href { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And variable `bool flag`

In my response I need only `href` and `id` fields if `flag` equals `true`. And if `flag` equals `false`, I should return all fields.

My GET method is implemented through the code:

```
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{    
    [OperationContract]        
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
         UriTemplate = "Response/{*id}?fields={fieldsParam}")]
}
```

This functionality is need for supporting `fields` request param.

I found `EmitDefaultValue` attribute for non serialization, but it works only with default values.

Should I customized serializer or data attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Newtonsoft. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

> To conditionally serialize a property, add a method that returns
>   boolean with the same name as the property and then prefix the method
>   name with ShouldSerialize. The result of the method determines whether
>   the property is serialized. If the method returns true then the
>   property will be serialized, if it returns false then the property
>   will be skipped.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeManager()
    {
        // don't serialize the Manager property if an employee is their own manager
        return (Manager != this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it doesn't work with the default serializer. I use answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118504/how-to-set-json-net-as-the-default-serializer-for-wcf-rest-service) to change my GET method. After that it works.