# WCF Rest - Incoming camelCase Json to PascalCase object

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have my WCF REST endpoint which receives POST from an Angular service in JSON format which is **camelCase**. Since the classes on WCF is PascalCase, I would like to know if there is a way to deserialize the incoming request from camelCase to PascalCase object?

Basically, my request variable is null since the .net deserializer won't deserialize anything due to case mismatch.

```
[OperationContract]
[System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "POST",  
        RequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "updatePackageConfig")]
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message updatePackageConfig(List<UpdatePackageConfigRequest> request);
```

Comment: Can you show the model class which is supposed to be the response?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to look at response model class, my question is more on incoming request. For response I had the same issue where my service was returning pascal case but angular expect camel. I used  System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.CreateTextResponse